# Why is Bayes Success Run Theorem independent of total "population" size?

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, quality-control

In Bayes success-run theorem (below), total "population" size is not a parameter.  Why is this?

$$R = (1-C) ^{ (1/n)}$$
where:

- $R =$ Reliability (or probability of success),
- $C =$ confidence level,
- $n =$ sample size.

Comment: We could use more contextual information: in particular, *exactly how is the sample obtained*?

Comment: Randomized sample

Comment: That doesn't help much, because there are many ways of obtaining random samples.  You need to be specific (because the answer depends on it).

Comment: Simple random sampling.  500 units (each with unique IDs) are being sampled and a computer will generate a randomized list of n units from the set of 500 units.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80851/919 for a good discussion.  That answer makes it clear that the theorem applies to sampling from a *process*, not a finite population.  In your case--assuming you are limiting your conclusions to just those 500 units--a finite-population correction is certainly possible.